# Drop down menu changes order and removes one choice each time - Python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Python drop down menu changes order each time it is ran and removes one choice each time. How do you fix this.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Menu")

menu = Frame(root)                         

menu.pack(pady = 5, padx = 50)

var = StringVar(root)

list = {
    '1',
    '2',
    '3',
    '4',
}

option = OptionMenu(menu, var, * list)
var.set('Select')

option.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

Do not use a `set` (an unordered structure) to define your options, use a `list`, e.g.:

```
options = [  # notice the square bracket
    '1',
    '2',
    '3',
    '4'
]
option = OptionMenu(menu, var, options[0], *options)  # make sure you define a proper default
# etc.
```

As for the removal of the first element - it was happening because you didn't define the third argument to `OptionMenu` which sets the default value so your first options element was expanded into it.

P.S. It's a very, very bad idea to name your variables/functions the same name as built-in types (e.g. `list` in your case).